# How to call Kotlin class key in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

We're making Dagger module for providing class as follows, but we encounter the problem.

`CustomHelper` is *.kt class, if we use `CustomHelper::class` into `@ClassKey`, it won't be recognized in Java and get syntax error.

Even if we change to use `CustomHelper.class` as follows, we still get compile error.

```
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(CustomHelper.class)  // <- not work
    static Helper provideCustomHelper(CustomHelper customHelper) {
            return customHelper;
    }
```

We will appreciate any help.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Comment: What does CustomHelper look like? and _what is the error_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your module build.gradle. Maybe you forget to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in top of build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For using `Kotlin` class you need to swap it to java class using `javaClass` method as in

```
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(javaClass<CustomHelper>())  // <- not work
    static Helper provideCustomHelper(CustomHelper customHelper) {
            return customHelper;
    }
```